# Why might the outputs passed to AudioWorkletProcessor's process() method contain an empty array?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audioworkletprocessor

Background: In the WebAudio API, an implementation of an `AudioWorkletProcessor` must provide a `process(inputs, outputs, parameters)` method that gets called by the system, with the system constructing the arrays being passed in depending on what is connected to the processor's `AudioWorkletNode`.  This documentation lives here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process

Question: Why might the `outputs` parameter contain nothing but an empty array?  In my `process()` method, I have code that looks like this:

```
process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    this.inputs = inputs;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.bufferLength = outputs[0][0].length;
    this.checkTimer();
    return this._process(outputs);
}
```

I'm getting an error that the browser can't read `length` of `undefined`, and looking closer, it's because `outputs[0]` is an array that contains 0 elements, so `outputs[0][0]` is undefined.  As far as I know, the audio node *is* hooked up to a destination node, so data ought to be flowing here.  But if I can better understand why `outputs[0]` is empty, I can better find the true source of the problem.

Note: I know that I don't actually need to get the buffer length here because it's always 128 anyway, but the `_process(outputs)` method does, obviously, need to fill this array eventually.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you ran into this [bug/fix](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/324293899) that recently landed in Chromium based browsers. There is also a related [spec discussion](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2566).

Please note that a render quantum may have more or less than 128 frames in the future.

https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2450

Comment: Could use some insight over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78174055/why-is-this-audioworklet-to-mp3-code-producing-different-results-on-chromium-and